# How can I disable first the message in devise ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am currently doing a project and using a devise gem.. Everytime I load the root(localhost:3000) it always display the "You have to confirm your email address before continuing.". The thing I want is it will only display the message after sign-up..

I tried to put if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name == 'registrations' inside of if (alert), can be found at devise/session/new.html.. I used this because I've saw inside of registrations there's signed_up_but_unconfirmed: (can be found at devise.en.yml)

Yes it's working, it wont display the message when I load the localhost:3000 but after I sign-up the message wont display. I searched regarding to this problem, I saw that they're recommending create a confirmation_controller. I already created that file but don't know how can I apply that..

Question: How can I disable first the "You have to confirm your email address before continuing.", it will only dispaly after sign-up

**Devise/session/new**

```
<% if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name == 'registrations'  
             if (alert)%>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <h5 class="text-center"><%= notice %></h5>
        </div>

        <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  # devise_for :users, controller => { :confirmations_controller => "confirmations/after_confirmation_path_for"}
  root to: "home#index"
end
```

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: Not yet sir and also I didnt confirm it yet..

Comment: Could you put your route.rb in your question please?

Comment: "I searched regarding to this problem, I saw that they're recommending create a confirmation_controller. I already created that file but don't know how can I apply that". Where did you see that?

Comment: How can I apply those controllers? registrations_controller, confirmations_controller and passwords_controller?